# Casting firestore observables to custom objects

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm new to angular and firestore and trying to figure out how to cast the data received from firebase directly to models. What is the best approach here?

Currently I get the data, but it looks like it's not casted into a Blimp object. When I try to call getImageUrl() on it in the view, I get the following error message.

> ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.getImageUrl is not a function

So my question: What is the best and cleanest way to cast these observables to the correct local model? I was expecting the  tags to cast it by default.

**Current code**

Custom model class

```
export class Blimp {


created_at: Date;
file_location: string;
id: string;

constructor() {
    console.log('OBJ');
}

getImageUrl() {
    return "https://*.com" + this.file_location;
}
```

}

***Service class***

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Blimp} from '../models/blimp';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {finalize} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlimpService {

   blimps: Observable<Blimp[]>;

  constructor(private fireStore: AngularFirestore, private fireDisk: AngularFireStorage) { }


  getBlimps() {
      this.blimps = this.fireStore.collection<Blimp>('blimps').valueChanges();

      return this.blimps;
  }
}
```

**Display component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {BlimpService} from '../../services/blimp.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Blimp} from '../../models/blimp';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blimp-viewer',
  templateUrl: './blimp-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blimp-viewer.component.scss'],
})
export class BlimpViewerComponent implements OnInit {

  blimps: Observable<Blimp[]>;

  constructor(private blimpService: BlimpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blimps = this.blimpService.getBlimps();
  }

}
```

**View**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let blimp of blimps | async">
      {{ blimp | json}}
      <img [src]="blimp.getImageUrl()" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Update #1**

Changed the code to

I now have changed your example to: getBlimps() {

```
   this.blimps = this.fireStore.collection<Blimp>('blimps')
          .valueChanges()
            pipe(map(b => {
                let blimp = new Blimp();
                blimp.created_at = b.created_at;
                blimp.file_location = b.file_location;
                blimp.id = b.id;

                return blimp;

            }));

      return this.blimps;
  }
```

This still complains in the view about the getImageUrl() not being found on the object.

**# Solution**

Looks like I forget a . (dot) in the last code

This code works:

```
this.blimps = this.fireStore.collection<Blimp>('blimps')
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map(collection => {
            return collection.map(b => {
                let blimp = new Blimp();
                blimp.created_at = b.created_at;
                blimp.file_location = b.file_location;
                blimp.id = b.id;

                return blimp;
            });
        }));

  return this.blimps;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Concept :

You don't cast an observable to an object model. An observable is a stream which has a lifecycle.
An **observable** emits value to **its subscribers**, you need to subscribe to your observable to be notified when it emits value. You also need to close the subscription or the subscription will last until your observable *complete* causing **memory leaks**.
I can see you're using `| async`in your *html template*, it's a subscription handled by angular that auto-unsubscribe when needed.

#### Get data :

You need to map the data you received to a `Blimp` object, you can use [map operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html).

```
blimps$: Observable<Blimp[]>; // naming convention, suffix your observable with $



blimps$ = this.fireStore.collection<Blimp>('blimps')
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(map(collection => {
                return collection.map(b => {
                    let blimp = new Blimp();
                    blimp.created_at = b.created_at;
                    blimp.file_location = b.file_location;
                    blimp.id = b.id;
                    console.log(blimp);
                    console.log(b);
                    return blimp;
                });
            }));

      return this.blimps;
```

As we changed `blimps` to `blimps$`, change your html template :

```
*ngFor="let blimp of blimps$ | async"
```

### EDIT :

You can use your class constructor to initialize your object :

```
export class Blimp {

created_at?: Date;
file_location?: string;
id?: string;

constructor(blimp: Blimp = {}) {
  this.created_at = blimp.created_at;
  this.file_location = blimp.file_location;
  this.id = blimp.id;
}

getImageUrl() {
    return `https://*.com${this.file_location}`; // use string interpolation here
}



blimps$ = this.fireStore.collection<Blimp>('blimps')
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(map(collection => {
                    return collection.map(b =>  new Blimp(b));
                }));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. However, in your example shouldn't there be a subscription? The map function also doesn't work on valueChanges(). Can you also please clarify why you use blimps$ (what does the $ do?). Thanks

Comment: @W.Loockx I edited the answer, you need to use `map` inside `pipe` operator. You don't need a subscription because you use `| async` inside your html template which handles the subscription. I used `blimps$` because naming convention requires all observables to have $ as a suffix. :)

Comment: When I add a console.log to the map function, it doesn't log anything.

Comment: Added the solution as it works! Thanks! If you know a better way to instantly assign the object members instead of line by line, please post.